# Android Preferences "Send Feedback"

Tags: android, email, android-intent, preferences

I'm trying to add a "Send Feedback" option in my settings. The subject and text work fine. But the email address will no be accepted. What can I do, that the email is accepted, because that's the important extra I think!?

```
<Preference
    android:title="Send Feedback">
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.SEND"
        android:mimeType="text/email">
        <extra
            android:name="android.intent.extra.EMAIL"
            android:value="mailto@email.com"/>
        <extra
            android:name="android.intent.extra.SUBJECT"
            android:value="Feedback"/>
        <extra
            android:name="android.intent.extra.TEXT"
            android:value="Text of Feedback"/>
    </intent>
</Preference>
```

Comment: how are you sending the email?

Comment: when i select the preference, a intent chooser is shown and i select gmail. or what do you mean?

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
<Preference
    android:title="@string/pre_title_feedback"
    android:summary="@string/pre_summary_feedback">
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:data="mailto:my@email.address">
        <extra
            android:name="android.intent.extra.SUBJECT"
            android:value="Feedback"/>
        <extra
            android:name="android.intent.extra.TEXT"
            android:value="Text of Feedback"/>
    </intent>
</Preference>
```